# how to get value from a widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created simple demo of color pick widget...

I have a container which is wraped with GestureDetector...

when i tapped on container a colorpalletewidget appears for color selection, and on clicking ok...container color should be changed based on selected color...

**Like DatePicker we get a date from datePicker widget**

here is the code

```
Scaffold(
          body: GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
             showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
                return Dialog(
                  child: ColorPalleteWidget(),
                );
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              color: //selected color from ColorPalleteWidget,
            ),
          )),
```

here is my customColorPalleteWidget

```
class ColorPalleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
   ColorPalleteWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ColorPalleteWidget> createState() => _ColorPalleteWidgetState();
}

class _ColorPalleteWidgetState extends State<ColorPalleteWidget> {
  Color selectedColor=colorlist[0];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: colorlist.length,
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 7,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ColorDotWidget(
                      isSelected: selectedColor == colorlist[index],
                      color: colorlist[index],
                      onPressed: (){
                        setState(() {
                          selectedColor=colorlist[index];
                        });
                      });
                }),

            Row(children: [
              TextButton(onPressed: (){
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              }, child: Text('Save'))
            ],)


          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass back a value in `Navigator.of(context).pop()` and `await` your dialog.
Here is the code how to await your dialog. Be aware that you have to check if color is null. This can happen if you call Navigator.pop(context) without passing a value e.g. with Back Button or tapping outside of the dialog.

```dart
Scaffold(
          body: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
             final color = await showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
                return Dialog(
                  child: ColorPalleteWidget(),
                );
              });
             if(color != null){
                // Do something with the color
             }
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              color: //selected color from ColorPalleteWidget,
            ),
          )
         ),
```

Here is the code  to pass back a value of your dialog.

```dart
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(selectedColor);
  },
  child: Text('Save'),
);
```

Comment: Yes it is solved....now i get a one more question..what if widget is not inside showdialog..will post demo what i mean to..hope to get answer from u

Comment: upvote my question if u think its helpful to others

Comment: can u pls solve this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76697359/how-to-get-value-from-custom-widget-in-flutter